# New service worker keeps being added

Tags: service-worker, polymer-starter-kit, polymer-2.x

I'm using polymer and firebase to make a web app, and the generated service worker is acting weird.

[image: screen shot of what is happening]

So, as you can see, the number of "clients" keeps increasing overtime. A new client is added like every 5 seconds.

What is a possible cause of this?

Comment: I'd imagine that it has something to do with you deleting the SW registration while there's a tab still open that relied on it. It might be confusing the DevTools interface? Do you see the same thing when you haven't deleted the SW registration?

Answer (score 0):

My guess here is that you have a lot of tabs open.  I saw that happen to my project when I opened up another tab of the same URL.  Or you might be missing some event listeners for the SW.

Comment: I actually thought that the cause might be having too many tabs all opening the same page, so I closed all the other tabs and cleared the storage, but the same thing still happened.

What's weird is that this "keeps on registering SW every 5 seconds" thing only happens when I have the dev tools opened. When I close the dev tool and refresh the page, and after the page has loaded reopen the dev tool, the SW is working properly.